# android retrofit await method to finish outside of response

Tags: android, android-asynctask, async-await, retrofit

I need to run a BroadcastReceiver to make a webcall in the background and display a notification to the user via notificationmanager. However, the method is running synchronously and displaying a notification before the webcall is finished. How do i await the void method that contains the retrofit webcall?
Below is the web method i need to await.

```
public static void getFriendList(String id, final ApiInterface api, final MainActivity activity, final boolean isUpdate)
{
    Call<List<String>> call = api.getFriendList(ServiceGenerator.API_KEY, id,"friend");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<String>> call, Response<List<String>> response) {
            try {
                List<String> idsList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String idGroup : response.body()) {
                    idsList.add(idGroup);
                }

                for (String ids : idsList) {
                    getPlayerSummaries(ids, api, activity, isUpdate); // another web call
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("TEST----------------------FAILED IN RESPONSE" + ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("TEST----------------------FAILED IN FAILURE" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if you want asynch call then use call.execute

Answer (score 0):

False. Execute is for Synchronous calls. Anyways, I think I figured out a solution. I will use sync calls inside an async task. This way, I know when it's finished outside of the web method.